# Eclipse - Start Tomcat server from a JUnit

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, junit

This question has probably been asked before but perhaps a fresh new answer is waiting somewhere.

I am building a Webapp in Eclipse using Tomcat. The app has a `@WebListener` that provides a file polling service. The file poller and a couple of other little bits such as an HttpClient call won't work (properly) unless Tomcat is runnning.

I have Tomcat embedded in Eclipse and everything works fine. Stop/Start etc. In fact the polling service works fine too. However, I'd like to know if there is a way to automate the starting of Tomcat from within my JUnit test case.

I'm simply trying to save a single click to start the server. Worse case scenario is that I just perform the click and run the test suite.

Comment: You are refering to the process of embedding tomcat into your unittest. Using these keywords a famouse search engine showed up this document:

http://people.apache.org/~markt/presentations/2010-11-04-Embedding-Tomcat.pdf

Comment: I personnaly use grizzly to start a web server in my test cases. Something like private static HttpServer SERVER = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(<my-uri>, <my_application>);

Comment: @Matthias that PDF looks interesting. I'm going to take a look at that. I wasn't actually trying to embed Tomcat into my Unit Tests but it actually looks simple enough to do this. I'm surprised.

Comment: FWIW, Tomcat's own unit tests use the embedded server for just that purpose. Feel free to check out the source code to see how Tomcat [eats its own dog food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food).